# Tensorflow Access CsvDataset values

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, eager-execution

**Eager execution**

I have been digging through the API for 2 days and I cant seem to find a way to use the data from a `CsvDataset` object.

I have the following sample from a dataset:

`70,1,4,130,322,0,2,109,0,24,2,3,3,2
67,0,3,115,564,0,2,160,0,16,2,0,7,1
57,1,2,124,261,0,0,141,0,3,1,0,7,2
64,1,4,128,263,0,0,105,1,2,2,1,7,1
74,0,2,120,269,0,2,121,1,2,1,1,3,1
65,1,4,120,177,0,0,140,0,4,1,0,7,1
56,1,3,130,256,1,2,142,1,6,2,1,6,2
59,1,4,110,239,0,2,142,1,12,2,1,7,2
60,1,4,140,293,0,2,170,0,12,2,2,7,2
63,0,4,150,407,0,2,154,0,4,2,3,7,2`

I read the csv as said in their high-level APIs video:

```
tf.enable_eager_execution()
defaults = [tf.float64] * 14
dataset=tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset(path, defaults)
>>> dataset
>>> <CsvDataset shapes: ((), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), ()), types: (tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64)>
```

But from here on i cant acess any data like, getting the values of a column.

Converting the dataset to a list using: `list(dataset)` is not an option, as it takes a very long time with normal size csv's (~190k samples).

So, is there any way to get column or row values from this object? Or is there really no point in using TF to read data instead of using scikit/pandas?

**Edit 1:**
Tried doing `col1 = dataset.map(lambda *row: row[0])` as said by @kvish, this return  a `<MapDataset shapes: (), types: tf.float64>` which is iterable. Problem is that having to loop over every column and then iterating over every `MapDataset` would make the complexity `O(n^2)`.

The idea output would be a list of tensors, each tensor containing all values from a column, similar to this:

```
[<tf.Tensor(shape=(10,), dtype=float64, 
numpy=array([70.0,67.0,57.0,64.0,74.0,65.0,56.0,59.0,60.0,63.0]))>,
(...) x14]
```

Comment: To get row values, you simply need to define an iterator. 
Here are [examples](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#creating_an_iterator) of various iterators available.
As far as the columns go, thats an interesting question. I am not familiar methods available to do that but one thing that you can easily do is define a new dataset object. 
for example col1 = dataset.map(lambda row: row[0]). This object would contain the entire column 1. You can then define an iterator like what you did above to iterate through it.

Comment: @kvish Will check that, running tests to compare to my current pandas function. Will post results soon, much apreciated.

Comment: if you are running tests, then I would encourage you to look at the [Input Pipeline Performance Guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/datasets) to get a better idea about leveraging optimizations.

Comment: Is the input pipeline appropriate for eager? I don't need a continuous flow of data, just reading and splitting a dataset.

Comment: if that's the case, you might not have much use for that in the eager setting. But it's still useful to maybe apply transformations like feature columns if you want to use estimators to train your data

Comment: @kvish ok so `col1 = dataset.map(lambda *row: row[0])` (had to be unpacked) returns a `<MapDataset shapes: (), types: tf.float64>` that can be iterated, but that would require an extra loop to "merge" all the tensors into one unique tensor containing all the column values, which would raise the complexity to (On^2) since i would have to loop all columns and then all iterables.

Comment: if you need everything in one tensor without looping through the iterator, you can use the [batch](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#batch) function and set the batch size to the number of rows, if you know the number of rows already. If you do not know the number of rows in advance, you can use the [group_by_reducer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/group_by_reducer) method, but I do not know how easy this is to use!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so with the help of @kvish i was able to find reach solution. Number of rows and columns needs to be known beforehand in this solution.

```
col_list = []
append = col_list.append
to_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor
for i in range(0,cols):
    col = dataset.map(lambda *row: row[i])
    col = to_tensor(*col.batch(rows))
    append(col)
```

This will output the desired:

```
>>> col_list
[<tf.Tensor: id=256, shape=(10,), dtype=float64, numpy=array([70., 67., 57., 64., 
74., 65., 56., 59., 60., 63.])>, <tf.Tensor: id=282, shape=(10,), dtype=float64, 
numpy=array([1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.])>, <tf.Tensor: id=308, shape= 
(10,), dtype=float64, numpy=array([4., 3., 2., 4., 2., 4., 3., 4., 4., 4.])>, 
<tf.Tensor: id=334, shape=(10,), dtype=float64, numpy=array([130., 115., 124., 128., 
120., 120., 130., 110., 140., 150.])>, <tf.Tensor: id=360, shape=(10,), 
dtype=float64, numpy=array([322., 564., 261., 263., 269., 177., 256., 239., 293., 
407.])>, <tf.Tensor: id=386, shape=(10,), dtype=float64, numpy=array([0., 0., 0., 0., 
0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.])>, <tf.Tensor: id=412, shape=(10,), dtype=float64, 
numpy=array([2., 2., 0., 0., 2., 0., 2., 2., 2., 2.])>, <tf.Tensor: id=438, shape= 
(10,), dtype=float64, numpy=array([109., 160., 141., 105., 121., 140., 142., 142., 
170., 154.])>, <tf.Tensor: id=464, shape=(10,), dtype=float64, numpy=array([0., 0., 
0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0.])>, <tf.Tensor: id=490, shape=(10,), dtype=float64, 
numpy=array([24., 16.,  3.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  6., 12., 12.,  4.])>, <tf.Tensor: id=516, 
shape=(10,), dtype=float64, numpy=array([2., 2., 1., 2., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2., 2.])>, 
<tf.Tensor: id=542, shape=(10,), dtype=float64, numpy=array([3., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 
1., 1., 2., 3.])>, <tf.Tensor: id=568, shape=(10,), dtype=float64, numpy=array([3., 
7., 7., 7., 3., 7., 6., 7., 7., 7.])>, <tf.Tensor: id=594, shape=(10,), 
dtype=float64, numpy=array([2., 1., 2., 1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2., 2.])>]
```